# Render Visualforce page as PDF in landscape orientation

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I've done it before but recently it does not appear to be working. Tried changing the api to an older version, still nothing. Not sure what else to try. i've tried multiple 'solutions' from other related posts, but they all seem to be from 2015 and earlier, back when those solutions worked for me. Anyone know what has been changed and how to accomplish this currently? The most recent post I found suggested this:

```
@page {  
                 size: A4 landscape; /* ISO/JIS A4 (210mm�297mm) */  
                 margin: 5mm; 
              } 
        @page:first {  
                 size: A4 landscape; /* ISO/JIS A4 (210mm�297mm) */ 
                 margin: 5mm; 
                 margin-top: 3mm; 

              }
```

But that doesn't work either. here is a snippet of what I have now:

```
<apex:page StandardController="Opportunity" Extensions="ProjectInformationExt" renderas="pdf">

<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JqueryMin}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Project_Info_Scripts}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.ClearanceScripts}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.ClearanceStyle}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.DipStyle}" />
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.RFC_ViewAsReport}" />
<head>
<Style>
    @page {  
             size: A4 landscape; /* ISO/JIS A4 (210mm�297mm) */  
             margin: 5mm; 
          } 
    @page:first {  
             size: A4 landscape; /* ISO/JIS A4 (210mm�297mm) */ 
             margin: 5mm; 
             margin-top: 3mm; 

          }  
    .label{
        font-size: 13px;
        color: #000;
    }
</Style></head>
<span class="hidden" id="pid">{!project.id} </span> 
<apex:image url="{!$Resource.OPICLogo}" width="50" height="50"
    style="float: left;" />
<h2 class="text-left" style="float: left; color: black;">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <apex:outputField value="{!project.name}" />
</h2>
<br style="clear: both;" />
<br style="clear: both;" />

<div class="bold text-right" style="float: right;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="nopad">Report Date:&nbsp;<apex:outputText id="outDate" value="{!currentDate}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<!--<apex:outputText value="{!findip.id}"/>-->
<div class="bold text-right" style="clear: both; float: right;">

    Project Information for&nbsp;
    <apex:outputField value="{!project.ProjectID__c}" />
    <br />
</div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to use `applyBodyTag="false"` attribute in `<apex:page` tag as explained in [Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_renderas_pdf.htm) to render the PDF properly. I checked with the below code and I am able to render the PDF in landscape mode.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
    <head>
        <style>
            @page{
                size: A4 landscape;
            }            
            body {
                font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS';
            }
            .companyName {
                font: bold 30px; color: red;
            }  
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
        <h1>New Account Name!</h1>

        <apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="100%">
            <apex:outputText value="{!account.Name}" styleClass="companyName"/>
            <apex:outputText value="{!NOW()}"></apex:outputText>
        </apex:panelGrid>
        </center>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: If the fix worked, please mark it as answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 4):

Post-API version 27, you need to have the `<html>` tag in your VF page for

`@page {
   size: landscape
}`

to work, plus you'll need to apply `applyHtmlTag="false"` to the apex:page tag. So your code above would need to be:

`<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                @page{
                    size: A4 landscape;
                }
            ... rest of your code here ...
        </head>
    </html>
</apex:page>`

Comment: you also need
    showHeader="false"

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page {
            size: A4 landscape;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    ... rest of your code here ...
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Use the HTML Tag Post-API **version 27**
Also If you are using HTML tag all your styling will work too inside style tag